# How to replace authentication links with custom routes?

Tags: 8, navigation

I am working on a custom Drupal 8 module that has its own authentication form.

For this, I created a Drupal page with the custom authentication form, i.e. I have a route at `drupalsite.com/custom-signup`

What I am not able to figure out is how can I replace Drupal's default Register and Login links which are scattered everywhere on the website to point to above route. I don't want to redirect from `/user/login` page to `/custom-signup` as I still want to allow admin to login. For all other users except admins should be redirected to `\custom-signup`.

I could use jquery to brute-force my way to replace the links, but is there an efficient way to achieve this?

TL;DR: I need to replace following default Drupal links using my module.

[image]

**Update:**

Following the first solution, I added the routing files as follows, the links are redirecting me to my custom form.

[image]

However, when I try to enter `user/login` manually in the URL, I get `page not found` message on the website.  [image]

Comment: You could just change the user auth class from core to your own implementation. When checking authentication, if the username/email matches user id 1 or a certain role, you can let Drupal just authenticate it without using the external service or however you are implementing new authentication.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, not sure how to implement it. Can you please point me to some sample code on overriding core classes to my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to alter the route, in your custom module add:

**mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php**

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Change path '/user/login' to '/customn-login'.
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setPath('/custom-login');
    }
    // Change path '/user/register' to '/custom-signup'.
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.register')) {
      $route->setPath('/custom-signup');
    }
  }

}
```

**mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

For more in depth information, see [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

---

If you still want `/user/login` to work, then you can create a new route for it.

**mymodule/mymodule.routing.yml**

```
mymodule.login:
  path: '/user/login'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm'
    _title: 'Log in'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
```

Remember to clear all caches to see changes.

Comment: Thank you. When I try to go to `/user/login` I get `the requested page could not be found` error, even though I can navigate to `/custom-login` by manually typing in the address bar.

Comment: If I use `$route->setPath('/user/login')`, i.e. replacing the `user/login` with itself, it works. That means the code is working, but it's not able to find the `/custom-login` path.

Comment: So you want to still have `/user/login` path so admins can login there and a `/custom-login` path for everyone else?

Comment: Exactly. I tried the above solution, but somehow it's not redirecting me to `/custom-login`.

Comment: @akshayKhot probably because you have not cleared the cache. Although, my solution above removes the `/user/login` and instead uses `/custom-login` which is not exactly, half way there, to what you want since you still want `/user/login` to work.

Comment: I did clear the cache multiple times. I think I am missing something very simple like wrong name or location, etc. Can you have a look at my code in the updated question?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this exact solution wouldn't work for my specific case as I need the admin to still log in at `/user/login` but still, it would be neat to learn how to alter the paths.

Comment: I don't know what changed, but this time I cleared the caches and the links are working. So they do redirect me to my custom form. When I try to enter `/user/login` manually in the URL, I still get `page not found error`. 
I guess this solves the above question(of changing URLs) but leaves with my specific case of allowing admin login. Any thoughts? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Will `/user/login` be rendering the same custom login form? or the original/default drupal login form?

Comment: If I enter `/user/login` in the URL, it results in error, see the updated question. But if I click on `Register` or `Login`, it takes me to my custom form.

Comment: @akshayKhot yes I get that, `/user/login` is not working yet, but which form would you like to show up when you go to `/user/login` ? the custom or the original?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to show the default Drupal login form, using which the admin can log in.

Comment: @akshayKhot see updated answer.

Comment: That's genius. It's working exactly as I wanted it to work. I wish I could mark this twice as an answer. Thank you so much for your help with this, really appreciate it.

Comment: I am wondering how come these two routes don't conflict with each other, i.e. when admin tries to go to `user/login`, why Drupal doesn't redirect it to `/custom-form`?

Comment: @akshayKhot it's because Drupal uses the **route name** rather than the path. Anyting that uses the `user.login` route points to `/custom-login` and anything that uses `mymodule.login` route points to `/user/login`. The login link in your question's screen shot uses the `user.login` route.

Comment: The mymodule.login route which has path of `/user/login` points to **_form: '\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm** which is the original drupal login form. So this is why there is no conflict.