# Alter existing 'Log In' route so URL includes request_uri as query string

Tags: 8, routes

I am trying to alter the existing 'Log In' URL so that it points to a certain location and also includes  the REQUEST_URI as a query string that is not encoded. How do I do this?

Based on this article, [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) and this [SE answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/251742/101335) I can change the 'Log In' URL so it points to a different location (/login). What I can't seem to figure out is how to add a query string that isn't encoded.

This code:

```
$route->setPath('/login?destination=' . \Drupal::request()->server->get('REQUEST_URI'));
```

Gives me:

```
/login%3Fdestination%3Dpage2
```

What I want is:

```
/login?destination=page2
```

I have looked into [RequestContext::setQueryString](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21RequestContext.php/function/RequestContext%3A%3AsetQueryString/8.1.x) and [Route::addOptions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/function/Route%3A%3AaddOptions/8.9.x) but can't seem to get anything to work.

Full code:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\myModule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
* Listens to the dynamic route events.
*/
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */

    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        // Change path '/user/login' to '/login'.
        if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
            //$route->setPath('/login');
            $route->setPath('/login?destination=' . \Drupal::request()->server->get('REQUEST_URI'));

        }
        
        // Always deny access to '/user/logout'.
        // Note that the second parameter of setRequirement() is a string.
        if ($route = $collection->get('user.logout')) {
            $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** There is also a cache issue when you do it in a route subscriber, as the path value stays the same.

Comment: The easy solution would be to append the param part to the login link's `href` via JS

Comment: @NoSssweat, I was hoping you would chime in since I used your answer from long-ago. Using JS is a heck of a lot easier and seems to work like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to have a look to PathProcessors, you might do something like that:

**mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
mymodule.path_processor:
  class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\MymodulePathProcessor
  tags:
    - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 250 }
```

**mymodule/src/PathProcessor/MymodulePathProcessor**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class MymodulePathProcessor.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor
 */
class MymodulePathProcessor implements InboundPathProcessorInterface {
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if ($path == '/user/login') {
      $request_uri = $request->server->get('REQUEST_URI');
      return "/login?destination={$request_uri}";
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the cache before to try it.

You might need the `processOutbound` function too in which case you'll need one more line in your service

**mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
mymodule.path_processor:
  class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\MymodulePathProcessor
  tags:
    - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 250 }
    - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 250 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /node/14" in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest() (line 137 of vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).`

Comment: Is the node published and can anonymous user access this content type in your permissions (asking but I am pretty sure it's not the problem since you would get a 403 exception not a 404) ? /node/14 route is `entity.node.canonical`. That error is weird unless the content doesn't exist

Comment: It's published and accessible to anyone. I tried different pages like the homepage and same result. It even occurs when logged in as admin (user 1).

Comment: "You might need the processOutbound function too" ... yes but only proccessOutbound(), where you can add the query parameter to $options and also the context `url.path`to the bubbleable metadata to get caching right. The inbound path processor is not necessary and doesn't work BTW because paths are handled in path processing without query parameters. Those are stored in the request if you need to change them inbound.